# Titanium + Watch app with valid provisioning will not build

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

The app, watch, and watch extension all have valid enterprise provisioning profiles selected. I created these in the developer portal. For some reason appcelerator will always claim it can't find the provisioning files. (Even though I see them in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisiong Profiles). These are all enterprise provisioning profiles.

```
[ERROR] :  iOS extension "App" target "App WatchApp" has invalid provisioning profile UUID in tiapp.xml.
[ERROR] :  Unable to find a valid provisioning profile matching the UUID "xxxxxxx-b4ea-458e-ade5-542b1de1d7ed".
```

Here is a more details output from using ti build with my configuration.

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.12.4
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 8
  Memory                      = 17179869184

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 4.8.2
  npm Version                 = 4.5.0

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.12

Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 6.2.0.v20170510071058
  SDK Path                    = /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.2.0.v20170510071058
  Target Platform             = iphone

Command
  /usr/local/Cellar/node@4/4.8.2/bin/node /Users/username/.appcelerator/install/6.2.0/package/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js build --platform ios --build-only --force-copy -T dist-adhoc --config-file /var/folders/tw/l7_bcdgx3mn8k7m36k_3qgrh0000gp/T/build-1494442724047.json --log-level info --no-banner --project-dir /Users/username/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/App
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has this problem I believe I tracked it down.

The ioslib library was updated to include separating enterprise from adhoc provisioning profiles recently.

The code for finding a provisioning profile in the titanium_mobile ios build file was also updated to search in this new location but the extensions portion was not updated to do so.

If you want need the fix its here...

https://github.com/gregpardo/titanium_mobile/commit/a7a263f5ec4f9622e3d19ac918d28f4f0f6391da